# Is this sentence correct? “House that i lived in for the first year of my life”

Tags: sentence-structure

I am not a native english speaker. Can somebody please tell if this is correct sentence 
House that i lived in for the first year of my life

Comment: As is stands, no. You need to add something else to the sentence. Do you mean it's a large house? Do you mean you liked the house? Are you simply trying to say *this* or *that* is the house?

Comment: I was just posting a picture of a house and adding a caption. In that case, am i right?

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to a specific house, so you need a definite article. When referring to yourself, 'I' should also always be capitalized.

“The house that I lived in for the first year of my life...”

That gives you a sentence fragment, because you've only mentioned the house. A sentence generally needs a verb: 'A dog' is not a sentence, 'A dog ran' is.

“The house that I lived in for the first year of my life was made of brick.”

That's an acceptable sentence.